# Multiple Aviary Feather

Tags: javascript, aviary

I've a issue on the integration of the Aviary Feather.
In my javascript I need to use Feathers like this:

```
// Aviary init
var featherProductEditor = new Aviary.Feather({
  apiKey: 'myapykey',
  apiVersion: 3,
  theme: 'dark',
  tools: 'all',
  appendTo: '',
  onSave: function(imageID, newURL) {
    // Do things for featherProductEditor
    console.log('featherProductEditor');
    // Close the editor
    featherProductEditor.close();
  }
});

// Aviary init
var featherContentBlockEditor = new Aviary.Feather({
  apiKey: 'myapykey',
  apiVersion: 3,
  theme: 'light',
  tools: 'all',
  appendTo: '',
  onSave: function(imageID, newURL) {
    // Do things for featherContentBlockEditor
    console.log('featherContentBlockEditor');
    // Close the editor
    featherContentBlockEditor.close();
  }
});
```

Then I call the two Feather

```
featherProductEditor.launch({ ....
```

and

```
featherContentBlockEditor.launch({ ....
```

but the only "**onSave*:**" callback called is the second one of the "**featherContentBlockEditor**" var

Why? How can I solve this?

Comment: Have you tried whether the `onError` or `onReady` callbacks are called instead of `onSave`?

Comment: Yes, I've already tried, the onError do not return anything.
The onReady always call the second feather initialized

Comment: What are you providing in the `x.launch({ ...`? Since that object is a config override, it'd be nice to know what's there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**For your first question, why only the second `onSave` is called ?**

Internally, the Aviary Web SDK stores the feather config in `AV.launchData`, and `AV` is an alias of the `Aviary` global variable. This is the code snippet from the `Aviary.Feather` function:

```
AV.Feather = function (config) {
    ...
    AV.launchData = AV.util.extend(AV.baseConfig, config);
    ...
}
```

So, that means `featherContentBlockEditor`'s configuration will override the `featherProductEditor`'s configuration.

You can verify this by adding `AV.launchData.onSave()` after the creation of each feather.

**For your second question, How can I solve this ?**

No, you can't without hacking into the SDK. This is how Aviary Web SDK works, only define one instance of `Aviary.Feather` per page.

Answer (score 1):

**How can you solve it?**

You can use `imageID` to identify which instance of Aviary produced the onSave event.

```
  onSave: function(imageID, newURL) {
    if(imageID === 'productImg') {
      // Do things for featherFeatureEditor
      console.log('featherProductEditor');
    } else {
      // Do things for featherContentBlockEditor
      console.log('featherContentBlockEditor');
    }
    // Close the editor
    featherContentBlockEditor.close();
  }
```

Use `image:'productImg'` for the launch configs for your product image.

Answer (score 0):

You can only have one instance of the Aviary editor on a given page, but you can reuse it by calling:

```
  editor.close(true); // passing true forces an immediate close without triggering shutdown animation
  editor.launch({ image: new_id, url: new_url });
```